# Can't get Custom Fonts to display in production (Heroku)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku, fonts, sass

My custom fonts display in development mode, but in production on Heroku, they don't work. My fonts are in assets/fonts/, and this is part of the code I have:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'SamsungOne800';
  src: url(/assets/SamsungOne-800_v1.0.eot);
  src: url(/assets/SamsungOne-800_v1.0.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"), 
    url(/assets/SamsungOne-800_v1.0.ttf) format("truetype"), 
    url(/assets/SamsungOne-800_v1.0.woff) format("woff"), 
    url(/assets/SamsungOne-800_v1.0.svg#icofonts) format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

When I run `heroku logs`

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/SamsungOne-800_v1.0.ttf"):
```

I tried adding gem 'rails_12factor' for production and precompiling assets but nothing changed. Help?

Comment: You said your fonts are in `assets/fonts/` then why `url`s don't contain `fonts/`? When you write address like this `/address/...` you should start addressing from root folder.

Comment: @ata Based from what I've seen online, some only use assets folder, some just use the font name only. Anyways, I tried your method, no difference.

Comment: Did you read tutorials about file path like: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp ? If it doesn't help, tell me path of your php file and also CSS file, I would help if I could.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify `assets`, try changing your urls:

`src: url(/assets/SamsungOne-800_v1.0.eot);`

to:

`src: url('SamsungOne-800_v1.0.eot');`

You need to do the same for other `url`.

Comment: how about `asset-url` instead of `url`?

Comment: what is css error? What is your file style? css or scss?

Answer (score 0):

Moved all my code from `landing.scss` to `application.css`(after renaming it to application.css.scss). Edited my code to a simpler version,

```
@font-face{
        font-family: 'SamsungOne800';
  src: asset-url('SamsungOne-800_v1.0.ttf');

}
```